# Performance issue when using union

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

Currently im using union and this causing ]performance issue and also  long running session . Can i use #temptable instead of union? i have written below query and using left join as well.

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON;  
      
     SELECT * FROM (   
        (SELECT DISTINCT si.num, si.code, 1 AS action_code  
          FROM stock si (NOLOCK)  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN product dpx (NOLOCK) ON si.owner_my_id = dpx.my_id  
          AND si.my_id = dpx.my_id  
          AND si.num = dpx.num  
          AND dpx.active_flag = 1  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_page dpcx (NOLOCK) ON si.owner_my_id = dpcx.my_id   
          AND si.my_id = dpcx.my_id   
          AND si.num = dpcx.num   
          AND dpcx.active_flag = 1  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dsi dsi (NOLOCK) ON si.owner_my_id = dsi.my_id  
          AND si.my_id = dsi.my_id  
          AND si.num = dsi.num  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN loadtable ilr (nolock)   
          ON si.my_id = ilr.my_id   
          AND si.num = ilr.num  
          AND getdate() between ilr.eff_date AND (end_date+1)  
          WHERE si.my_id = @my_id  
          AND si.owner_my_id = @my_id  
          AND (dpx.my_id IS NOT NULL OR dpcx.my_id IS NOT NULL OR dsi.my_id IS NOT NULL OR ilr.my_id IS NOT NULL) )  
          UNION  
          (SELECT DISTINCT dp.num, '-2' AS code, 0 AS action_code  
          FROM distributor_product dp (NOLOCK)  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN product dpx (NOLOCK) ON dp.my_id = dpx.my_id  
          AND dp.num = dpx.num  
          AND dpx.active_flag = 1  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_page dpcx (NOLOCK) ON dp.my_id = dpcx.my_id   
          AND dp.num = dpcx.num   
          AND dpcx.active_flag = 1  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dsi dsi (NOLOCK) ON dp.my_id = dsi.my_id  
          AND dp.num = dsi.num  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN loadtable ilr (nolock)   
          ON dp.my_id = ilr.my_id   
          AND dp.num = ilr.num  
          AND getdate() between ilr.eff_date AND (end_date+1)  
          WHERE dp.my_id = @my_id  
       AND (dpx.my_id IS NOT NULL OR dpcx.my_id IS NOT NULL OR dsi.my_id IS NOT NULL OR ilr.my_id IS NOT NULL)  
          ) ) a   
         
    END
```

Comment: Try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. (The selects return no common rows, and both are doing select distinct.)

Comment: *Can i*.... why don't you try?

Comment: Also note that `nolock` is not a free "go faster" hint, it has consequences

Comment: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Using some white space to format your queries would make them so much easier to read. This wall of text is so difficult to decipher. Also that date calculations you have are less than ideal. Between is pure evil when it comes to dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common and you should use dateadd instead of that shorthand +1.

Comment: Those date functions in your join are non-sargable which is likely not helping your performance here but I suspect there are some other issues going on as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's a complex query. Some optimizations surely will depend on the indexes on your various tables. You didn't tell us about those.

Here are some suggestions.

- Use `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION`. `UNION` deduplicates the result set; that can be time-consuming for large result sets due to the data shuffling and comparisions required to deduplicate. It won't change your result set.
- Stop using `DISTINCT` if you possibly can. Same performance problems as `UNION ALL`. But it's not clear from your question whether you can stop using `DISTINCT`.
- When troubleshooting this performance problem, get rid of your `NOLOCK` qualifiers. They probably don't help much anyway.
- If you must use NOLOCK semantics because you get deadlocks when running this query, use the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` statement right before this query, instead of burying NOLOCKs in the query. Deadlocks sometimes occur when you do historical reporting against active transactional tables.

  But be aware that NOLOCK semantics can generate bogus results, especially from actively changing rows in transactional databases. Avoid `LOCK` and `READ UNCOMMITTED` if you possibly can. With respect, using those is sloppy programming.
- Troubleshoot this performance issue by working with one branch of your UNION ALL, then the other.
- In SSMS, right-click on the query (the branch of UNION ALL) and choose Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query, then look at the plan. Sometimes actual execution plans show a recommendation for adding an index to one of your tables.

If these suggestions don't help you, please don't hesitate to ask another question. But if you do, please ...

- Ask about just one branch of your UNION ALL to keep things simpler.
- Show the table definitions, with indexes and approximate row counts, of all the tables involved.
- Use Brent Ozar's [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) web app to show us the actual execution plan.

**Edit** Can you use inner joins rather than left joins?

When you do `rightT LEFT JOIN leftT ON rightT.something = leftT.something` you get all rows from rightT, even those that don't match the ON condition. Your result set contains NULL values from the missing leftT columns.

But if you do `rightT INNER JOIN leftT ON rightT.something = leftT.something` you don't get the rows from rightT unless they match the ON condition. INNER JOIN suppresses the non-matching rows.

Only you can answer the question about switching to INNER JOIN for some or all of your query's JOINs: you understand your database design much better than some rando on the 'toobz (that's me). If you still get a useful result set with the suppressed not-matching rows, you can switch.

Comment: Can i change from left join to inner join .

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Hi if there is multiple session running this query causing long running session

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkvNuK1pq  This is my query plan URL

Comment: i even finetune the query https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1h3KFya9, when there is multiple session running its causing long running session

Comment: please see my comment